# Get all attributes but not methods

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm trying to create a function which prints all attributes of my class. It seems to work good but there is a one problem - it prints methods too which I don't want to.

```
 def print_all(self):
            attributes = [attr for attr in dir(self) 
              if not attr.startswith('__')]
            for attr in attributes:
                if getattr(self, attr) == None:
                    continue
                value = str(getattr(self,attr)) 
                print attr + ':' + value
```

Could you advise me how to avoid printing methods?

Comment: So you only want un[`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) attributes? Also, you should test for `None` by *identity*, not *equality* - `if foo is None:`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why should I test it by identity? thanks

Comment: @Milan because `None` is a singleton.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you little elaborate it please? I dont get it because its work.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? I don't understand what *"I dont get it because its work"* means.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for my english :D I dont understand why should I use is instead of == (it works with ==)

Comment: Because, per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), *"Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not `, never the equality operators."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the keys from the class descriptor `__dict__` e.g.

```
for key in self.__dict__:
    print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_all_attrs(some_object):
    for var in dir(some_object):
        if not callable(var):
            print "{} is an attribute".format(var)
```

`callable` returns True/False for whether or not you can call the variable like a function. This should even work if the attributes are properties, unless you're doing weirdness like

```
   class BadObj(object):
        @property
        def x(self):
            return lambda: 3 + 2
```

...but you probably weren't doing that anyway.